# svelte - call function from specific component in a series of nested components

Tags: javascript, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a `nested` component, that I will instance multiple copies in the app:

```
//App.svelte
<Nested /> // Nested-1 
<Nested /> // Nested-2
<Nested /> // Nested-3
```

in `Nested` I have export a function:

```
//Nested.svelte
export function doExample(){...}
```

What is the best way for me to call `doExample()` in `Nested-2`? One way i can think of is using `id` at the `Nested`:

```
//App.svelte
<Nested id="nested_1" /> // Nested-1 
<Nested id="nested_2" /> // Nested-2
<Nested id="nested_3" /> // Nested-3
```

then use `getElementById()` to identify the specific component then call the function. But is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this by using `bind` on the instance and then call the function on that instance

```html
<script>
  import Nested from './Nested.svelte'
  let child
  
  const action = () => child.doExample()
</script>

<Nested bind:this={child} />
```

Note that this would also work with an array:

```html
<script>
  import Nested from './Nested.svelte'
  let children = []
  
  const action = i => children[i].doExample()
</script>

{#each array as item, i}
  <Nested bind:this={children[i]} />
{/each}
```